# Using HTML Agility Packet to get several Tables from a Website and add them to List

Tags: c#, html, html-table, html-agility-pack

I am working on a little program that is getting Table information from a website and will later sort this information by DateTime.

My biggest problem is that after my function that gets the website and makes it into a string, I cannot find a way to get the information into a list. I keep getting NullPointer errors.

I tried this:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string page = webClient.DownloadString("http://www.mufap.com.pk/payout-
report.php?tab=01");

HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(page);

List<List<string>> table = 
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@class='1']")
        .Descendants("tr")
        .Skip(1)
        .Where(tr=>tr.Elements("td").Count()>1)
        .Select(tr => tr.Elements("td")
        .Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim()).ToList())
        .ToList();
```

But for some reason I keep getting this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in WebGetter.exe
```

I think this has to do with the class I am selecting, though the table's class is named "1", so this should have the right reference. When I use the

I keep getting this:

`System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]]`

If you can point me into the right direction, that would be nice.

Comment: Forgot to mention that this is the link that I am using: 
https://www.athletic.net/TrackAndField/Division/Top.aspx?DivID=81830

Comment: There isn't any table with class `1` in your given url

Comment: @RubenVardanyan Then how do I get the first table there? I am pretty new to this :s

Comment: So you mean first table element when you wrote `class=1`? @Colin

Answer (score 0):

If you need to select first `Table` element from the HTML you just need to use `SelectSingleNode` method. It returns the first node for your query, and your query should look like this

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table")
```

In your code you add query also to `class` with not existing value. As I understand form your comments above, you thought that `[class='1']` will return the first `Table` element, which is wrong, it will return `Table` element which's `class` attribute value is `1`